# ERC223 Transfer Arguments

Tags: solidity, erc-223

There are 2 transfer functions in Dexaran's ERC223 contract. One includes data and the other one doesn't. Does this mean we should choose one transfer function to use in our contracts and ignore the other?

Also, what if a contract only includes the transfer with data function:

`transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data)`

And someone calls the function but doesn't include a data parameter? Will the function fail, or will it assume the _data is something like "0x" and perform the function with that?